# How can I find where an object was allocated with memory profiler?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, user-interface, memory-leaks

I have a GUI application that runs for several hours with semi-stable memory status (+-50MB). After a few hours for some reason the memory increases quickly (about 100MB per minute) until it throws OutOfMemoryException.
I don't know what is the event that causes this behavior but when I take a dump of the app and open it with Visual Studio's "Debug Managed Memory" I can see that most of the memory is taken by MemoryStream and System.Drawing.Internal.GPStream objects and I don't have info about which objects hold those objects.

[image: Screenshot of memory profiler]

From what I found in google, the GPStream might be an Image that was not disposed. My application contains third party GUI components and I can't analyze all the code.
Is there a way to know how those objects were created? It will also be helpful if I could extract the file name or something identifying from the object's byte array, so I could know which GUI component it represents.

Comment: I'd probably start with [this list of all places which create a `GPStream`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Windows.Forms.Primitives/Interop/Ole32/Interop.GPStream.cs,471d6021704e2af8,references), and work from there

Comment: I'm not that familiar with VS memory profiler, but there is usually some way to view a "retention-graph" to view objects that are keeping the reference alive. But I'm not aware of any tool that can track allocations.

Comment: @canton7, I'm not sure if the GPStream you referred me to is the same as the one I'm seeing.  Yours is part of ole32 and mine is from namespace System.Drawing.Internal.

Comment: @JonasH, as you can see in the print screen, in VS "Paths to Root" should contain the objects that are holding GPStream but in my case there is no clue. Maybe because it is an unmanage memory type.